# Custom "Use", "Cancel",“Retake” and "Reverse Camera" button event using UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

I am making a custom photo picker. so i have used

```
imagePickerController.showsCameraControls = NO;
```

And i have created one camera overlay view and use

```
imagePickerController.cameraOverlayView = overlayView;
```

So, I need to implement custom button option, Can anyone please tell me how can i give customize button event using UIImagePickerController?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can build a UIViewController, take it's view as the image picker's overlayView.
All your custom buttons are controlled by this UIViewController.

e.g.

```
UIButton *myBtn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:btnFrame];

[myBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(myBtnPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[overlayView addSubview:myBtn];
```

Comment: I have been using custom overlay for UIImagePickerController.  I have added button so what event i need to use.

Comment: what do you mean "what event"? if you are in old version Xcode, you use .xib to custom your UI, else in storyboard. The point is , there should be one controller to take care for respond to user action. you can build a new controller to do it or use the one that UIImagePickerController lies in

Comment: @Jingdude.. i m not using any xib or storybaord . i have created custom buttons programmatically .

Comment: then you can use    `addTarget:action:forControlEvents:`

Comment: e.g.

    `UIButton *myBtn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:btnFrame];`

    `[myBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(myBtnPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];`

    `[overlayView addSubview:myBtn];`

Comment: thanks ....Go to the below link and see my answer....i have solved....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16933811/creating-a-preview-screen-with-a-custom-camera/16937825#16937825

Comment: @AnandGautam I think this is what you were referring, Here is the take picture action you can call to take picture programmatically `[imagePickerController takePicture];`

Comment: @PrasadYes, you are correct. but i was doing record in my app using  [imagePickerController startVideoCapture];