# iOS camera view - get size of camera area

Tags: ios, uipickerviewcontroller

Is there a way to find out the height of the camera view only(not the picker view)?  I need to know so I can centre the cross hairs on my overlay view vertically - screenshot below

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an option - you can create custom camera overlay view with all custom controls on positions you want and then set:

```
imagePickerController.cameraOverlayView = yourOverlayView;
imagePickerController.showsCameraControls = NO;
```

Source and more info: [in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16933811/creating-a-preview-screen-with-a-custom-camera)