# UIImagePickerController custom FlashMode button is not working on IOS 10 (swift)

Tags: ios, swift, camera-overlay, camera-flash, cameraoverlayview

I know that a question of this type is already asked but I Debugged it in bit detail, and i came to this point that when i switched this flag off

```
   self.picker.showsCameraControls = false
```

then the custom flash button doesn't respond but if I'll change the flag to

```
   self.picker.showsCameraControls = true
```

then my custom flash button responding OK, I have check all the delegates and flags but I am not able to pin point the bug, either it is in my code or it is in IOS 10 version, if its in my code then on showing camera controls why my custom flash button changes state of flash and work fine.
here is my code for better understanding:

```
   func configureImagePicker(){
         self.picker.delegate = self
         self.picker.allowsEditing = false
        if       UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera)
    {
        self.picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera
        self.picker.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeImage as String]
    }
}

  func showImagePicker(){
    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera){

        self.picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera
        self.picker.showsCameraControls = false
        self.picker.delegateController = self
        self.picker.delegate = self
        self.picker.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeImage as String]
        self.picker.allowsEditing = false


        if let cameraOverlay = self.picker.cameraOverlayView {

            self.createCamerOverlay(cameraOverlay.frame)
            self.picker.cameraOverlayView = self.overlayView


            self.presentViewController(self.picker, animated: false, completion: {
                dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(Double(0.5)*Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))), dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                    if self.picker.cameraDevice == UIImagePickerControllerCameraDevice.Rear && UIImagePickerController.isFlashAvailableForCameraDevice(UIImagePickerControllerCameraDevice.Rear)
                    {
                        if Float.init(UIDevice.currentDevice().systemVersion) < 11.0
                        {
                            switch(Global.shared.currenFlashOption)
                            {
                                case .FlashOff:
                                    self.picker.cameraFlashMode = .Off
                                    let flashImage = UIImage(named: "btn-flash-off")
                                    self.flashButton.setImage(flashImage, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
                                    self.flashButton.setImage(flashImage, forState: UIControlState.Highlighted)
                                case .FlashAuto:
                                    self.picker.cameraFlashMode = .Auto
                                    let flashImage = UIImage(named: "btn-flash")
                                    self.flashButton.setImage(flashImage, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
                                    self.flashButton.setImage(flashImage, forState: UIControlState.Highlighted)
                                case .FlashOn:
                                    self.picker.cameraFlashMode = .On
                                    let flashImage = UIImage(named: "btn-flash-on")
                                    self.flashButton.setImage(flashImage, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
                                    self.flashButton.setImage(flashImage, forState: UIControlState.Highlighted)
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            self.picker.cameraFlashMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashMode.On

                        }
                    }
                });
            });

        } else {
            print("Camera overlay frame not found. So did not present the controller.")
        }
    }
    else{
        let alert = UIAlertView(title: "Error", message: "Camera Not Available", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "Cancel")
        alert.show()
    }
}
```

In short my custom flashmode button is not working on cameraoverlayview. 
if there is no solution to this problem then please suggest any hack.
thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've solved my problem with a clumsy hack,

```
 self.picker.showsCameraControls = true
 self.picker.cameraFlashMode = .On
 self.picker.showsCameraControls = false
```

It is fast enough to not disturb user with the showing and hiding controls.
It Worked!

Comment: Zaraki it is a flaw in iOS version, i hope they will definitely figure it out in coming updates i reported it to apple too, and i don't figure why it isn't working but its a hack to trigger the delegate...