# How to create full screen camera interface without toolbar?

Tags: ios, user-interface, camera

I've been looking around the internet for ages now and I can't seem to find my answer anywhere! Basically, I want to create a full screen camera interface similar to SnapChat. I don't want the bottom toolbar as I want to be creating my own "Snap" buttons.

I found a few things but the references are like five years old now.

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16852601/custom-use-cancel-retake-and-reverse-camera-button-event-using-uiimagep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to my question - most answers of the internet pointed me to using UIImagePickerController - instead I used AVFoundation. Found a great little tutorial here:

https://www.invasivecode.com/weblog/a-very-cool-custom-video-camera-with/